# RegEx - match digits but exclude digits with specific numbers in beginning and match all characters but exclude specific word

Tags: regex, range, notepad++, digits

I will have to do a Job with Invoices and Custumer IDs. The problem is that the order is mixed up, so no easy Excel Worksheet is possible but Regex.

I’ve tried various stuff (e.g. Lookahead and Lookbehind) but no luck. I’m a beginner in RegEx so it’s hard for me to find the working solution. Now I’m at a point where I need to ask for help.

My Goal is to …

1. Match all Customer ID digits and replace them with empty space but
   not match the 110xxxx Invoice Numbers
2. Match [A-Z] but exclude the word Invoice.

The data have the following requirements:

- The Invoice nr starts always with 110xxxx (8 digits)
- The Customer ID (i.e. CID) **never** starts with the number 110xxxx
- Sometimes the CID has 7 digits and sometimes 8 digits

It looks like this example

```
Invoice 1100348 Phil McDoe CID 2689578
CID 1234567, Invoice 1109781, -82, -83 John Miller
Invoice 1109785, CID 8912345, Franklin Barnes 
Invoice 1103249 James Brandlin CID 1165278
Invoice 1103678 Josh Grace CID 7513648
```

Comment: To anyone down-voting, please recognise that this is a new user and an explanation as to *why* you down-vote will help them write better questions in future. To Hendrik, is this a one-off job (e.g. migrating from one system to another) or will it have to be done many times (e.g. every day/week)? And does it have to be done in a single pass or will you be happy to accept a multi-step answer?

Comment: I upvoted your question because it's legit and clear. I'll try to help you.

Comment: @Tuga: for the sake of clarity, I did not down-vote (and don't know who did). I simply asked for clarification of the extent of the question. Knowing the expected outputs for the given range of inputs will help, too, as always.

Answer (score 0):

**1 - To remove the CID:**

1 - Open the desired archive on NotePad++
2 - Hit `CTRL + H`
3 - Choose the tab `Replace`
4 - On the `find` field type `CID (\d+)`
5 - On the `replace` field type `CID`

**BEFORE:**

```
Invoice 1100348 Phil McDoe CID 2689578
CID 1234567, Invoice 1109781, -82, -83 John Miller
Invoice 1109785, CID 8912345, Franklin Barnes
Invoice 1103249 James Brandlin CID 1165278
Invoice 1103678 Josh Grace CID 7513648
```

**AFTER:**

```
Invoice 1100348 Phil McDoe CID 
CID , Invoice 1109781, -82, -83 John Miller
Invoice 1109785, CID , Franklin Barnes
Invoice 1103249 James Brandlin CID 
Invoice 1103678 Josh Grace CID
```

**2 - To remove the word INVOICE:**

1 - Hit `CTRL + H`
2 - Choose the tab `Replace`
3 - On the `find` field type `INVOICE (110\d+)`
4 - On the `replace` field type `\1`

**BEFORE:**

```
Invoice 1100348 Phil McDoe CID 
CID , Invoice 1109781, -82, -83 John Miller
Invoice 1109785, CID , Franklin Barnes
Invoice 1103249 James Brandlin CID 
Invoice 1103678 Josh Grace CID
```

**AFTER:**

```
1100348 Phil McDoe CID 
CID , 1109781, -82, -83 John Miller
1109785, CID , Franklin Barnes
1103249 James Brandlin CID 
1103678 Josh Grace CID
```

Let me know if it this that you wanted.

Comment: Thank you. Your is good, but created an example that is simplified, because it is complicated enough to explain. My Situatuation is more complicated. I will try to explain